# Simple '$().show()' not working in 'if/else if' statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, show

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Shmoyojoe/2eCUa/2/) is the fiddle.

I am trying to make a div show by using `$().show()`, but it is not working. I suspect it is because it's in a `else if () {...}`, but I am not sure.

The `if/else if` statement:

```
if (i !== "" && ii !== "" && iii !== "") {
    $('#dialog').show();
        $('#dialog').dialog({
            modal: true,
            dialogClass: 'no-close',
            buttons: [{
                text: 'OK',
                click: function () {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            }]
        });
    } else if (i === "" || ii === "" || iii === "") {
        $('#error').show();
    }
```

Comment: Your else if statement is redundant, if none of the variables are empty then you can safely assume at least one of them has a value. A simple else will suffice here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is not `.value()` it is [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

```
    var i = $('#input').val();
    var ii = $('#input2').val();
    var iii = $('#input3').val();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/nhvZb/)

Comment: @JJP always look at the browser console to see whether there are any error

Comment: @ArunPJohny I checked my js on jsfiddle, and it didn't come up with any errors.

Answer (score 3):

in jQuery there is no `.value()` method. It should be as follows.

```
var i = $('#input').val();
var ii = $('#input2').val();
var iii = $('#input3').val();
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to replace .value() with .val()

Answer (score 3):

Just change the `$('#input').value();` to `$('#input').val();` for all the input values. It should work.